# Check if tautology (w/o truth table)

Tags: boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

$(A+B)(A+C)(B+C) = AB + AC + BC$  is a tautology (checked with Wolfram Alpha) and not hard to see if you apply duality principle $(invert + * 0 1)$
But how to prove with simplyfication
It'S not much but here's what I have so far :
$A+(BC)(B+C) = A(B+C) + BC$

And here I'm stuck.

Comment: Does $+$ mean "or" and multiplication mean "and"?

Comment: Yes (have to fill up with at least 12 characters to post the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lefthand side should give you $(A+BC)(B+C)$, not $A+(BC)(B+C)$. That in turn expands to $AB+AC+BC+BC=AB+AC+BC$ when you ‘multiply it out’, which is exactly what you want. Your $A(B+C)+BC$, though immediately obtainable from $A+(BC)(B+C)$, is actually obtainable from $(A+BC)(B+C)$, so apparently you were working with the correct parenthesization even if you didn’t write it. In any case, with $A(B+C)+BC$ you’re essentially done: it immediately expands to $AB+AC+BC$.

Comment: A question regarding the multiplying out. When you multiply the part BC * B and BC * C, the B and the C disappear because of the Idempotence Rule a*a = a ? And BC + BC = BC is also idempotence rule a+a = a.